# VB.Net launching multiple command line through Process.Startinfo

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading

I'm using VB.Net to launch multiple command line window (same exe file) through Process.StartInfo. I would like to have those windows running at background without hanging main UI thread that launch them and at the same time able to get the output of those external window to show progress at progress bar.

Here is a summary of what I'm trying to achieve but need further advise which way is feasible

```
- launch multiple exe command through Process.StartInfo
- don't want the external exe to hang my main UI thread
- need to get feedback from external exe to update progress bar which is placed at main UI thread
```

Let me know if I should supply more information. Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use Process.Start() to start each process
- don't call `WaitForExit()`
- add an eventhandler for the `Exited` event so you can report feedback

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use threading to achieve this, creating each new process in a separate background thread.

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4272/net-threading-part-ii/6/